Pytorch looses precision when converting numbers into tensors
How come PyTorch makes such a weird mistake in higher digits in division?
a = torch.tensor(1.0/10.0)`

print("{:.10f}, {:.10f}, {:.10f}".format(1.0/10.0, torch.tensor(1.0/10.0), a))

Output:
0.1000000000, **0.1000000015**, **0.1000000015**

My Python version is 3.12.4 and Torch is 2.3.0.post100.

Probably dropping from 64 bit to 32 bit floats. Try doing the same exercise casting that same value in numpy from np.float64 to np.float32 and see if you observe the same rounding error

This is a numerical precision error. Using 64 bit floats matches python.
a = 1.0 / 10.0
b = torch.tensor(1.0/10.0, dtype=torch.float32)
c = torch.tensor(1.0/10.0, dtype=torch.float64)

print(f"{a:.10f}, {b.item():.10f}, {c.item():.10f}")
> 0.1000000000, 0.1000000015, 0.1000000000

print(a == b.item(), a == c.item())
False True


I wonder if we can set pytorch to 64 bit float once during the code. Is it possible?

Yes, follow to set torch to use double precision https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/64-bit-double-math-based-inference-in-pytorch/60998

import torch    
a = torch.tensor(1.0/10.0, dtype=torch.float64)
print("{:.10f}, {:.10f}, {:.10f}".format(1.0/10.0, torch.tensor(1.0/10.0), a))

It's normal that you can do that
